Migration to js_interop with Flutter 3.22
i'm trying to migrate my flutter code to Flutter 3.22 with package dart:js_interop
i met an error when i try to generate chrome extension with flutter build web --web-renderer html --csp
Here is my code

// ignore_for_file: avoid_setters_without_getters

@JS()
library awc;

import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:js_interop';

@JS('archethic')
external ArchethicJS? get archethic;

@JS()
class ArchethicJS {
  @JS('streamChannel')
  external AWCStreamChannelJS? get streamChannel;
}

@JS()
class AWCStreamChannelJS {
  @JS('state')
  external AWCStreamChannelState get state;

  /// This returns a promise.
  /// You must use `promiseTofuture` to call this from Dart code.
  @JS('connect')
  external Object connect();

  /// This returns a promise.
  /// You must use `promiseTofuture` to call this from Dart code.
  @JS('close')
  external Object close();

  /// This returns a promise.
  /// You must use `promiseTofuture` to call this from Dart code.
  @JS('send')
  external Object send(String data);

  @JS('onReceive')
  external set onReceive(Future<void> Function(String data) callback);

  @JS('onReady')
  external set onReady(Future<void> Function() callback);

  @JS('onClose')
  external set onClose(Future<void> Function(String reason) callback);
}

enum AWCStreamChannelState {
  connecting,
  open,
  closing,
  closed,
}

the errors are:
../archethic-wallet-client-dart/lib/src/transport/webbrowser_extension/webbrowser_extension.js.dart:14:7:
Error: The '@JS' annotation from 'dart:js_interop' can only be used for static interop, either through extension types or '@staticInterop' classes.
class ArchethicJS {
      ^
../archethic-wallet-client-dart/lib/src/transport/webbrowser_extension/webbrowser_extension.js.dart:20:7:
Error: The '@JS' annotation from 'dart:js_interop' can only be used for static interop, either through extension types or '@staticInterop' classes.
class AWCStreamChannelJS {
      ^
../archethic-wallet-client-dart/lib/src/transport/webbrowser_extension/webbrowser_extension.js.dart:11:27:
Error: External JS interop member contains an invalid type: 'ArchethicJS?'.
 - 'ArchethicJS' is from 'package:archethic_wallet_client/src/transport/webbrowser_extension/webbrowser_extension.js.dart'
 ('../archethic-wallet-client-dart/lib/src/transport/webbrowser_extension/webbrowser_extension.js.dart').
external ArchethicJS? get archethic;

